# Inserting data to U-SQL tables is taking too long?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Inserting data to U-SQL table is taking too much time. We are using partitioned tables to recalculate previously processed data. Insertion for the first time took almost 10-12 minutes on three tables with 11, 5 and 1 partitions and parallelism was set to 10. Second time insertion of same data took almost 4 hours. Currently we are using year based partitions. We tested insertion and querying without adding partitions and performance was much better. Is this an issue with partitioned tables?

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange that the same job would be taking that much longer for the same data and script executed with the same degree of parallelism. If you look at the job graph (or the vertex execution information) from within VisualStudio, can you see where the time was being spent?

Note that (coarse-grained) partitions are more of a data life-cycle management feature that allows you to address individual partitions of a table, and not necessarily a performance feature (although partition elimination can help with query performance). But it should not go from minutes to hours with the same script, resources and data.